# Required field not being required in some orders

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

The phone number field is required in my store during checkout but some orders are coming in without a phone number. Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: This is usually an issue with JavaScript conflicts or JavaScript not being loaded on the users browser as i had a similar issue recently with both IE and Edge i am yet to find a solution to this but will post once found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue both on IE/Firefox and Safari(Windows Desktop and Iphone/Ipad) have done some testing and found that the issue is with the validate Javascript not being loaded only after being placed into production this is not just issue with custom theme but standard magento luma theme. i will post my solution once I find out also will be posting this issue into the magento git issue tracking system

Comment: Any solutions? Still have this issue :(